# How can I count rows in a 1:N:N relation in a faster way?

Tags: mysql, sql

This question is a bit complicated to me, and I can't explain it in one sentence so the title may seem quite ambiguous.

I have 3 tables in my MySQL database, their structure is shown below:

1. word_list (5 million rows)

```
    +-----+--------+
    | wid | word   |
    +-----+--------+
    |   1 | foo    |
    |   2 | bar    |
    |   3 | hello  |
    +-----+--------+
```

2. paper_word_relation (10 million rows)

```
    +-----+-------+
    | pid | word  | 
    +-----+-------+
    |   1 |    1  | 
    |   1 |    2  | 
    |   1 |    3  | 
    |   2 |    1  | 
    |   2 |    3  | 
    +-----+-------+
```

3. paper_citation_relation (80K rows)

```
    +----------+--------+
    | pid_from | pid_to | 
    +----------+--------+
    |        1 |     2  | 
    |        1 |     3  | 
    |        1 |     4  |
    |        2 |     1  |
    |        2 |     3  |
    +----------+--------+
```

I want to find out how many papers contain word W, and cite the papers also contain word W.(for each word in the list)

I use two inner join to do this job but it seems extremely slow when the word is popular - above 50s (quite fast if the word is rarely used - below 0.1s), here is my code

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT a.pid_from, a.pid_to, b.word FROM paper_citation_relation AS a 
    INNER JOIN paper_word_relation AS b ON a.pid_from = b.pid
    INNER JOIN paper_word_relation AS c ON a.pid_to = c.pid
    WHERE b.word = 2 AND c.word = 2) AS d
```

How can I do this faster? Is my query not efficient enough or it's the problem about the amount of data?

I can only come up with one solution that I delete the words which occur less than 2 in the `paper_word_relation` table. (About 4 million words only occur once)

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  What indexes do you have on your tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only concerned with getting the Count, you should not be first getting the results into a Derived Table, and then Count the rows out. This *may* create unnecessary temporary tables storing lots of data in-memory. You can directly count the number of rows.

I also think that you need to count unique number of papers. Because of Many-to-Many relationships in `paper_citation_relation` table, duplicate rows *may* be coming for a single paper.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.pid_from) 
FROM paper_citation_relation AS a 
INNER JOIN paper_word_relation AS b ON a.pid_from = b.pid
INNER JOIN paper_word_relation AS c ON a.pid_to = c.pid
WHERE b.word = 2 AND c.word = 2
```

For performance, you will need following indexing:

- Composite Index on `(pid_from, pid_to)` in the `paper_citation_relation` table.
- Composite Index on `(pid, word)` in the `paper_word_relation` table.

---

<s>We *may* also possibly optimize the query further by reducing one join and use conditional `AND/OR` based filtering in `HAVING`. You will need to benchmark it though.</s>

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
      SELECT a.pid_from  
      FROM paper_citation_relation AS a 
      INNER JOIN paper_word_relation AS b 
        ON (a.pid_from = b.pid OR 
            a.pid_to = b.pid)  
      GROUP BY a.pid_from 
      HAVING SUM(a.pid_from = b.pid AND b.word = 2) AND 
             SUM(a.pid_to = b.pid AND b.word = 2)
     )
```

Comment: Thanks! But this modification does not improve much, still cost 65s. (66s originally). And the count is 9465 in this case. Is it the best time I can get with this amount of data?

Comment: @TomLeung what was the original count value ? Check my updated answer for why I think your count logic needs to be improved. Moreover, is there any indexing done on all the tables ?

Comment: Yes, I do need the DISTINCT logic (4333 after distinct). All column is indexed using BTREE NORMAL index.

Comment: @TomLeung can you add the composite indexing as specified  by me, and test.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should check out what is a composite index and give it a try! XD

Comment: Amazing! After composite indexed, this query only cost 5s!! Can I do it even faster?

Comment: @TomLeung I have tried out one more solution. Check the second part of the updated answer. You will need to benchmark it though.

Comment: It seems this solution is even worse than the original one with composite index, anyway you really help me a lot! Thanks.

Comment: Since MySQL 5.7, this query will not use temporary tables for the derived table.  The subquery will be merged into the outer query before optimization.

Answer (score 0):

After the first `1:n` join you get the same `pid_to` multiple times and your next join is no longer `1:n` but `n:m`, creating a possibly huge intermediate result before the final `DISTINCT`. It's similar to a CROSS JOIN and it's getting worse for popular words, e.g. 10*10 vs. 1000*1000 rows.

You must remove the duplicates before the join, this should return the same number as @MadhurBhaiya's answer

```
SELECT Count(*) -- no more DISTINCT needed
FROM 
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT cr.pid_to -- reducing m to 1
    FROM paper_citation_relation AS cr
    JOIN paper_word_relation AS wr 
      ON cr.pid_from = wr.pid
    WHERE wr.word = 2
 ) AS dt
JOIN paper_word_relation AS wr
  ON dt.pid_to = wr.pid  -- 1:n join again
WHERE wr.word = 2
```

If you want to count the number of papers which have been cited you need to get a distinct list of `pid` (either `pid_from` or `pid_to`) from `paper_citation_relation` first and then join to the specific word.

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM
( -- get a unique list of cited or citing papers
    SELECT pid_from AS pid -- citing
    FROM paper_citation_relation
    UNION -- DISTINCT by default
    SELECT pid_to          -- cited
    FROM paper_citation_relation 
) AS dt
JOIN paper_word_relation AS wr
  ON wr.pid = dt.pid
WHERE wr.word = 2 -- now check for the searched word
```

The number returned by this might be slightly higher (it counts a paper regardless if cited or citing).

Comment: Thanks, but your query result isn't consistent with @MadhurBhaiya's result, I know very little about SQL query optimization so I don't know why...

Comment: Are the number totally different or quite similar? You should find out, what result you actually want and double check if any of the queries return that. E.g. check for differences when you do `COUNT(DISTINCT a.pid_TO)` in @MadhurBhaiya's query.

Comment: Quite similar. I need that DISTINCT, because if a paper with word W cite many paper with W, it should only count once

Comment: I added another variation, which might return slightly different number due to different logic.